# ComboBox: How to show one property of Items when DropDown is open and a different one when DropDown is closed

Tags: c#, combobox, controltemplate, winui-3, visualstates

In a WinUI 3 desktop app, I have a list of objects, each with a `LongName` and an `Abbreviation` property (both strings). I'd like to use a `ComboBox` to select a specific item. When the `ComboBox` dropdown is closed, I'd like the `Abbreviation` of the `SelectedItem` to display in the `ComboBox` but when the dropdown opens, I'd like the list to use the `LongName`s.

For example, consider the `FooBar` class:

```c#
public partial class FooBar : ObservableObject
{
    public static readonly FooBar[] FooBars =
    {
        new("Foo1","Bar1"), new("Foo2","Bar2"), new("Foo3","Bar3")
    };

    public FooBar(string foo, string bar)
    {
        Foo = foo;
        Bar = bar;
    }

    [ObservableProperty] private string _foo;
    [ObservableProperty] private string _bar;
}
```

and the `ComboBox`:

```xaml
    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <ComboBox x:Name="TheComboBox"
                  SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedFooBar, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind classes:FooBar.FooBars}"/>
    </Grid>
```

I'd like `TheComboBox` to show the `Foo` property for each `FooBar` when `TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen` is `true`, and the `Bar` property when it's `false`.

[image: dropdown open] or [image: dropdown closed].

I've tried setting `ItemTemplate`, `DisplayMemberPath`, `ItemContainerStyle`, `ItemTemplateSelector`, various tricks in code-behind, and editing the `DefaultComboBoxItemStyle` but none of these seem to work to change the property displayed dynamically. Making the change in code-behind seems to trigger `SelectedItemChanged`, probably because the `Items` list changes (but I'm not sure). I tried editing the `DefaultComboBoxStyle` (paricularly the `VisualState`s) but it's not obvious to me where individual items are displayed there.

Does anyone have any ideas for this or tips on how I might go about it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution mostly based on XAML and [databinding with the x:Bind extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#properties-that-you-can-set-with-xbind) (I've used a `UserControl` to be able to put the converter resource somewhere because with WinUI3 you can't put it under the `Window` element):

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:classes="using:MyApp.Models">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <classes:VisibilityNegateConverter x:Key="vn" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ComboBox x:Name="TheComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind classes:FooBar.FooBars}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="classes:FooBar">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Foo}" Visibility="{x:Bind TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Bar}" Visibility="{x:Bind TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen, Converter={StaticResource vn}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

And the converter for the "reverse" visibility conversion between `Boolean` and `Visibility` ("forward" conversion is now implicit in WinUI3 and UPW for some times)

```
public class VisibilityNegateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Note: I've tried to use [function binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings) to avoid the need for a converter, something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Bar}" Visibility="{x:Bind TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen.Equals(x:False)}" />
```

But compilation fails miserably (maybe a bug in XAML compiler?)

Comment: Thank you @Simon, this approach makes sense to me. When I tried something like this, the `Visibility="{x:Bind TheComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}"` bindings in the `TextBlock`s failed because _The property 'TheComboBox' was not found in type 'FooBar'_. How do you reference the parent control in a `DataTemplate`?

Comment: No, it builds, runs and works fine. It's just the visual editor that complains.

Comment: Very odd. But it works! I has a resource lookup in the test code that I forgot to remove. It's strange, though, that the function binding doesn't work. That exact code works in other places in my XAML. Thank you again - this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of a hack by adding an event to any of the change events

```
private void myComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _comboBoxValue = myComboBox.Text;//store the selected value elsewhere
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { myComboBox.Text = valueMapper[myComboBox.Text]; }); //idk how you're mapping the two strings
        //for all I know you might want ((Foo)myComboBox.SelectedItem).DisplayProperty 
}
```

This is a hack, there are other options though. Now that I think about it, a cleaner option would be to override the tostring of your objects dependent on whether or not the dropdown is open, back in a bit

OK plan B, not as clean code wise, but much cleaner UI wise. Recreate the underlying list after overriding the .ToString each time. This lets us use the dropdownStyle of dropDownList which is much cleaner

Note: the below code has the same class reflect itself in both string formats. You can do it with a dictionary lookup and populate with .keys and .values instead, either way works.

EventCode

```
private bool activateCombobox = false;
private void myComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Foo.IsDroppedDown = true;
        myComboBox.Items.Clear();
        myComboBox.Items.AddRange(fooItems);
    Foo.IsDroppedDown = false;
    activateCombobox = true;
}

private void myComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (activateCombobox)
    {
        activateCombobox = false;
        var selectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedItem;
        myComboBox.Items.Clear();
        myComboBox.Items.AddRange(fooItems);
        myComboBox.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }
        
}
```

and then our class code (change it to your classes ofc, this is just an example)

```
private Foo[] fooItems = new Foo[] { new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3) };
private class Foo
{
    public int index = 0;
    public Foo() { }
    public Foo(int index) { this.index = index; }
    public string dropdownFoo { get { return $"Foo{index}"; } }
    public string displayFoo { get { return $"Bar{index}"; } }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (IsDroppedDown)
            return dropdownFoo;
        return displayFoo;
    }
    public static bool IsDroppedDown = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TheLemon. I've tried your suggestions in quite a few different ways but I always seem to generate multiple `SelectedIndexChanged` events, or it just doesn't work. I actually started out by rewriting the `Items` list each time the dropdown opened or closed which is how I noticed the multiple change notifications. Ultimately, @Simon's answer worked for me.

Comment: @aturnbul that's what the activateCombobox flag was for haha, ensures only one trigger per time dropped down